# Why this VBA code to copy range fails intermittently?

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote below procedure to copy range of cells from an input sheet to output sheet. Output sheet is part of master template. After the copy, I call SaveAs function on master workbook to save the master workbook on file system with another name.

```
Private Sub copyRange(inputRange As Range, outputRange As Range)

inputRange.NumberFormat = "0.00000000"
inputRange.Copy
outputRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

End Sub
```

I'm calling this function multiple times from another procedure for each range that i want to copy. Calling code looks like this:

```
Dim InputSheet As Worksheet
Dim OutputSheet As Worksheet

Set InputSheet = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:/inputFile.xlsx", False, vbReadOnly).Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set OutputSheet = OutputSheet 'this is a sheet of master template

copyRange InputSheet.Range("E15:G28"), OutputSheet.Range("B12:D25")
copyRange InputSheet.Range("E33:G37"), OutputSheet.Range("B30:D34")

copyRange InputSheet.Range("I15:K28"), OutputSheet.Range("E12:G25")
copyRange InputSheet.Range("I33:K37"), OutputSheet.Range("E30:G34")

copyRange InputSheet.Range("M15:O28"), OutputSheet.Range("H12:J24")
copyRange InputSheet.Range("M33:O37"), OutputSheet.Range("H30:J34")
```

Above code keeps failing around 1 out of 5 times with error "*paste special method of range class failed*". Most of the time it runs fine and  output file is getting produced as expected. Is there any way to prevent this error?

Comment: Are all input and oputput ranges identically sized (same # of rows and columns)? Looks like this one isn't: copyRange InputSheet.Range("M15:O28"), OutputSheet.Range("H12:J24")

Comment: Per @jkpieterse's comment, you mismatched here: `copyRange InputSheet.Range("M15:O28"), OutputSheet.Range("H12:J24")`

Comment: I have fixed that but still keep getting the same error 1 out of 5 times.

Comment: Don't declare a worksheet variable with the same name as the codename of a worksheet in your template. There is no need for "Set OutputSheet = OutputSheet".

Comment: yeah. That is not the case. Have done that to make my code easily readable here. I am directly refering it.

Answer (score 1):

After trying many things, finally I've removed call to pastespecial method.

```
Private Sub copyRange(inputRange As Range, outputRange As Range)

inputRange.NumberFormat = "0.00000000"
inputRange.value2 = outputRange.value2

End Sub
```

This approach have resolve intermittent issues while copying the range.